# Unable to start Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: boot, ubuntu-mate

I have installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS.

At first it worked' then panel bar content wasn't show. I rebooted the PC and then when I tried to sign-in in it said 'failed to start session'. I tried to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into terminal, but when trying to sign in it said that I have typed the wrong password although typing the right pass(I used the numbers up from the QWERTY keyboard, caps lock weren't on)...

What should I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome, I'm not sure how you created your installation or install it, but seeing you're having so much trouble with this installation I would recommend just doing a fresh installation and see if this issues no longer exist